# Extract undocumented member functions selectively in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is there a prefered way to selectively extract member functions without documenting them?

I am aware of EXTRACT_ALL and the fact that grouped member functions (e.g. using ///\name MyGroup ///@{ ... ///@}) are always extracted.